# File metadata in Win32 C runtime library

Tags: c, windows, winapi, metadata, crt

I'm writing a Windows application in C and I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve metadata about files (specifically, it's the author information that I'm interested in). I've been up and down [Microsoft's list of functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/634ca0c2.aspx) and I haven't found anything that looks like what I want.

From Google and other Stack Overflow questions, I've found that NTFS stores metadata separately from the files themselves, so I'm guessing that just opening the files and looking for the metadata probably isn't what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is using the shell via the `IShellFolder2::GetDetailsEx()` API. This way you have access to any metadata the shell knows how to extract. There's an example [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/08/30/10202076.aspx) of using this interface to query items in the recycle bin, but the same technique applies to any folder.

Comment: My project is in C. Is there a C way to do this?

Comment: Yes you can, the headers define C interfaces as well (e.g. `IShellFolder2Vtbl`). You just need to get the interface pointer via `CoCreateInstance()` and then pass it as the first parameter to the C interfaces. There's a good introduction to COM here if you've never done anything with it before: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/633/Introduction-to-COM-What-It-Is-and-How-to-Use-It

Comment: You can also access the information "directly" without going through the shell APIs.  This metadata is stored in the [Summary Information property set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380376%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: It looks like COM + IPropertySetStorage is what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot everybody.